# Perform work before first request with bottle/Uwsgi/nginx

Tags: python, uwsgi, bottle

I have a bottle web server running with UWSGI and Nginx. Normally, if I start the script manually with

```
python app.py
```

I'm able to do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spawn_workers()
    init_workspace()
    run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

the issue is, when using UWSGI, is that it doesn't run the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part, because it just grabs the `app = application = bottle.Bottle()` part. This means I never have a chance to spawn background workers before the webserver is started.

What's the proper way around this? I see that flask has a `app.before_first_request` function, but I couldn't find anything that corresponds to that feature for bottle.

Comment: Already tried removing the `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not sufficient to just perform your initialization in `app.py`? E.g.,

```
# app.py
spawn_workers()
init_workspace()

app = Bottle()
```

Comment: it apparently is enough just to do that, not sure why it didn't appear to work for me but I tried it again and it did indeed work. Thanks.